# C# program using regex to print lines based on a value of a particular field?

Tags: c#, regex

I want my program to discard all the lines in which value of `appGUID` is either `wx` or `null`. How can I achieve this using a regex?

I am not able to figure out it's regex pattern. Please help.

My log file is of format :

```
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419422 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419442 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX New Bug: 3494441 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:bey81694 appGUID: wx
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX New Bug: 3494441 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:bey81694 appGUID: wx
INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX New Bug: 3494441 Server: yukon.corp.adobe.com User:bey81694 appGUID: wx
```

My code is here :

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Karan Logs\20110717.txt");
string x = reader.ReadToEnd();

List<string> users = new List<string>();

Regex regex = new Regex(@"appGUID:\s*(?<value>.*?)\s");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
        var user = match.Groups["value"].Value;
        if (!users.Contains(user)) users.Add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
appGUID:\s*(?<value>wx|null)\s
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this, but it is returning unique values of appGUID, i want all the lines with appGUID having duplicate values as well.

Comment: ok, what if i want to take both wx and null values and discard lines containing valuue in appGUID other than "wx" and "null". How will you define regex for that ?

Comment: @DorgySharma Sorry I dint get u... Isn't that the same as what it is doing right now?

Comment: appGUID:\s*(?<value>wx|null)\s  this will discard all the values of null and wx. I want it to consider values containing null and wx and discard other values

Comment: @DorgySharma The current regex is capturing values containing null or wx.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing all users with LINQ without regular expressions:

```
var users = File.ReadAllLines("20110717.txt")
                .Select(line =>
                {
                    string guidPrefix = "appGUID:";
                    int index = line.IndexOf(guidPrefix);
                    return line.Substring(index + guidPrefix.Length + 1);
                })
                .Where(user => user != "null" && user != "wx")
                .ToList();
```

If log format is not consistent (usually you should not rely on same format, because it should be flexible), then regular expression will be more appropriate. It will handle changing of appGUID position in line, or changing of text case:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"appGUID:\s*(?<user>\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var users = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt")
                .Select(line => regex.Match(line))
                .Where(match => match.Success)
                .Select(match => match.Groups["user"].Value)
                .Where(user => user != "null" && user != "wx")
                .ToList();
```

---

**UPDATE:** Actually I'd move parsing part into separate method, because this is thing which most probably will change. So, you have something like:

```
public List<string> GetUsersFrom(string fileName)
{
   return File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
              .Select(ParseUser)
              .Where(u => u != null && u != "null")
              .ToList();
}

private string ParseUser(string s) // Any implementation here
{
    var match = Regex.Match(s, @"appGUID:\s*(?<user>\S+)");
    if (!match.Success)
        return null;

    return match.Groups["user"].Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
var users = GetUsersFrom("20110717.txt").Where(u => u != "wx");
```

Comment: The user is not the appGuid. The user is the value after `User: ` part of the line.

Comment: @Cornelius `appGuid` is the thing OP calls `user`. Read question: `List<string> users = new List<string>(); if (!users.Contains(user)) users.Add(user);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
regularexpression.replace(@"(.*)?(wx|null)\b",.....)
```

and replace it with string.empty, it will discard all those lines which you don't want.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Karan Logs\20110717.txt");
string x = reader.ReadToEnd();

List<string> users = new List<string>();

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*)?(wx|null)\b");
var newString = regex.Replace(x, String.Empty);
```

Happy Coding

Comment: thanks for the resolution, here slight change in my requirements, what if i want my program to consider all those lines in which appGUID value is wx and null and rest it should discard.

Comment: Sir i tried your code but in last line of your code i.e. var newString = regex.Replace(x); it is giving error message saying - no overload for method takes arguments 1

Comment: Use this **regex.Replace(x, String.Empty);**

Comment: i will get all the values in newString, one more thing, i need to find out Unique "WX Edit bug" from values in newString, i have tried code but it is giving me wrong information :   Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*)?(wx|null)\b");
            var newString = regex.Replace(x, String.Empty);
            string discard = string.Join(",",newString);
            List<string> users = new List<string>();
            Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"WX Edit Bug:\s*(?<value>.*?)\s+Server");
            MatchCollection matches1 = regex.Matches(x);

Comment: Post a new question for it and i'll try to give you the correct solution. Please mark this post as correct answer if you got what you've asked in this question. Thanks Sharma :)

Comment: yes sir i got the solution. Actually there was a mistake in my code. regex1.Matches(discard)

Comment: Sir, what if i want to discard only those lines in which appGUID value is other than "wx" and "null". I mean vice-versa of this question.

Comment: var newString = regex.Replace(x, String.Empty); this line fails in case for multiple files. Issue is this is working only for one file.