# Using regular expressions to filter values in C#

Tags: c#

I want my program to discard all those lines in which value of "appGUID" is either "wx" or "null"

How can I achieve this using regex. After this it should return unique values of "WX Edit Bug". I tried but looks like some bug in my code.

I am not able to figure out it's regex pattern. Please help.

My log file is of format :

> INFO  [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: wx INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: wx INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3494430 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:xinche appGUID: null INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf INFO 
>   [com.adobe.watson.vo.BugServices] WX Edit Bug: 3419432 Server:
>   yukon.corp.adobe.com User:prerelease appGUID: fcdd2153-bbdf

My code is here :

```
IEnumerable<string> textLines
                          = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Dummy\", "*.*")
                            .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
                            .SelectMany(line => line);
            string x = string.Join(",", textLines);
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*)?(wx|null)\b");
            var newString = regex.Replace(x, String.Empty);
            string discard = string.Join(",", newString);
            List<string> users = new List<string>();
            Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"WX Edit Bug:\s*(?<value>.*?)\s+Server");
            MatchCollection matches1 = regex1.Matches(discard);
            foreach (Match match in matches1)
            {
                var Editbug = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                if (!users.Contains(Editbug)) users.Add(Editbug);
            }
            int WX_Edit = users.Count;
```

Comment: Just for clarity, can you show the expected output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15264675/470005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code you provided, and assuming the first part of your query works, you could try using a `Where` clause *(untested)*:

```
IEnumerable<string> textLines
    = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Dummy\", "*.*")
               .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
               .SelectMany(line => line)
               .Where(line => line.Contains("appGUID: null") || line.Contains("appGUID: wx"))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: bool does not contains a definition for to list

Comment: it gives an error: bool does not contains a definition for to list

Comment: yes it worked. You are genius. Now what if i want it to discard lines in which appGUID: null and appGUID: wx and print those lines in which value of appGUID is other than null and wx.